# "Jack believed that Bob said that Nancy saw Bill drove fast yesterday"?

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, syntactic-analysis, clauses

What is ungrammatical about this sentence?

> Jack believed that Bob said that Nancy saw Bill drove fast yesterday.

At the moment I have found out that the main verb,*believed*, is tensed, and the suboordinate clauses are complements of the verb. However, I am struggling with finding a mistake in this sentence. The only thing I can think of right now is that the word ''that'' is optional in tensed subordinate clause complements, but I am not sure if that's the actual error

Comment: I could swear I commented on this exact question yesterday—but  the question seems to have since been deleted. As I responded yesterday, the only thing that's actually ungrammatical is *drove* rather than *drive*.

Comment: @JasonBassford I didn't see the question yesterday but I found it by googling. Unfortunately, you need 10K rep to be able to see it.  The original sentence was in fact,  [*Jack believed that Bob said that Nancy saw Bill drove fast yesterday*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/448354/please-help-me-find-the-error-in-the-following-sentence). It's a shame the OP deleted it because the question had attracted three reopen votes, and the OP had made some valid observations, using quite sophisticated terminology. If I had known....

Comment: Limit it to the last clause :"Nancy saw Bill drove fast yesterday." is ungrammatical. Should be either "Nancy saw Bill drive fast yesterday." or "Nancy saw that Bill drove fast yesterday.

Comment: Also, this kind of question, 'find the error', is off-topic here. It might be OK on English Language Learners, but even there they expect some commentary, some prior research, some interesting question beyond 'fix this for me.

Comment: @Mitch Well, that depends on the meaning of *saw* there, doesn't it? "I see you fixed the tap then", "I see you drove fast yesterday" "Yes, I saw you drove fast yesterday". Ain't nothing particularly ungrammatical about those. Ain't no *that* required there at all.

Comment: @Mitch That intersesting info was in the original Q. Now copied in here.

Comment: @Lambie You cannot possibly know what is intended in that sentence. It's the inclusion of all the unnecessary *that*s before hand that garden path you in your reading of the last clause. And if the OP hadn't assumed there was something wrong, I doubt most people would have presumed there was. The OQ also  did a lot of garden-pathing.

Comment: @Araucaria As written, it does not work. Mitch is right. Because "Nancy understood (saw) Bill drove fast" is an unlikely meaning for the verb see over the arch of that particular sentence. Not in your examples.  Believed, said, and saw is not: believed, said, understood. Even though see as understood would be grammatical, it is most unlikely.

Comment: @Araucaria, you can be as sarcastic as you see fit, not recognizing that "see" **would have to mean** "understand" for it to work just shows your not wanting to concede the obvious.  That the meaning of "understand" for "see" here is really awkward. And I am outta here.

Comment: @Lambie There's no point in trying to tell the OP that *drove* is ungrammatical unless all of that's explained. In addition, it's all the unnecessary, pedantic *that*s beforehand that give that impression. Also Mitch's comment in no way at all discounts an *understand* meaning of *see* there. Very far from it. He actually says that *saw that* would be a good, grammatical version. That's only possible with the *understand* kind of meaning of *see* (understand/infer etc).

Comment: @Lambie My gently teasing previous comment was in response to your unedited original comment - and was in keeping with it. As you can see, when you edited your comment, I edited my response!

Comment: @Araucaria Unless all that's explained. Indeed. And I ain't gonna do that more than I already have.

Comment: Should one of the verbs be a past participle instead?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Ok, have had a go at an answer while I've been waiting here at my language school.

Comment: @Mitch Have done an answer for OP, which addresses  some of your points.

Answer (score 3):

> Jack believed that Bob said that Nancy saw Bill **drove** fast yesterday.

Whether there is an error in this sentence or not depends on which meaning of *see* the writer intends to convey. 
The verb *see* can take different types of Complement. The most common Complements are: a noun phrase, a content clause (just a normal tensed clause with no gaps in it), or a noun phrase plus non-finite clause:

1. Nancy saw [Bill]. <sup>*noun phrase*</sup>
2. Nancy saw [that Bill had been there]. <sup>*content clause*</sup>
3. Nancy saw [Bill] [steal the money]. <sup>*noun phrase plus non-finite clause*</sup>

In its most basic meaning, the verb *see* means something like: *to view with the eyes*. [(See definition 2 here)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/see). This is the meaning of this verb in examples (1) and (3) above.

Notice, though, that example (2) is different. It means something like *to become aware of something* or *to understand something*. In example (2), Nancy did not witness Bill being there, but she understood that fact from what she saw. When the verb *see* takes a content clause as a Complement, as in example (2), it normally has the *become aware of something/understand something* type of meaning.

**Content clauses in English**

Content clauses in English are often introduced by the word *that*. However, in most situations it's possible to omit this word. In fact, we can always omit *that* when the clause is a complement of a preceding verb<sup>1</sup>. So the following pairs of sentences mean exactly the same thing:

- Nancy saw [that Bill had been there].
- Nancy saw [Bill had been there].
- She realised [that she was losing].
- She realised [she was losing].
- You insinuated [that I was lying].
- You insinuated [I was lying].
- I think [that she loves you].
- I think [she loves you].

Notice that the verbs in these clauses are all tensed.

**See someone do something**

The noun phrase plus non-finite clause—or *see someone do something*—construction is used when the speaker wants to describe what event or situation was directly witnessed by the Subject of the verb *see*. If the noun phrase is a pronoun, it is accusative, not nominative. Notice as well, importantly, that the verb in the subordinate clause is in the plain form (sometimes called the *bare infinitive*). It cannot be past tense, and it cannot be present tense<sup>2</sup>:

- *I saw him **stole** the money. [ungrammatical, past tense verb]
- I saw him steal the money.
- *I  never see him **eats**. [ungrammatical, present tense verb]
- I never see him eat.

**The Original Poster's sentence**

Let's say that Nancy works at a haulage company. Her job, is to check the tachometers on the lorries (a tachometer is a device that measure the speeds that drivers were driving at and how far they drove). Now, let's say that Jack reported Bill for driving too fast yesterday - when, in fact he didn't. Jack's excuse is that it Bob's fault. The reason for this might be that:

- Jack believed that Bob said that Nancy saw Bill drove fast yesterday.

Now a different situation. The reason that Jack made the report this time is that Bob and Nancy had been at the pub. Bob subsequently tells Jack that Nancy witnessed Bill speed away from the pub in his lorry. In other words:

- Jack believed that Bob said that Nancy saw Bill drive fast yesterday.

Both of these two example sentences are completely grammatical. However, out of context, we might believe that the author of the Original Poster's sentence really intended a meaning like the one in the second example - even though they used the grammar in the first sentence. Why? Well, the author has used the word *that* at every opportunity, apart from in the very last clause. This might make us think that this is because the following clause is non-tensed and so *cannot* take the word *that*. Another reason to think this is that out of all the potential *that*s in this sentence, the one in the last clause would be the most important because it would make clear what the speaker intended.

However, there is no way of knowing what a speaker of a disembodied sentence was aiming at. Presumably, we must regard a potentially grammatical sentence as grammatical. If this is an example from a test, it is a badly devised one. The test writer could easily have avoided this problem if they had used a pronoun instead of the name *Bill*.

- *Jaqueline believed that Brenda said that Nancy saw him drove fast. (ungrammatical)

Or alternatively:

- *Jaqueline believed that Brenda said that Nancy saw he drive fast. (ungrammatical)

These would have been ungrammatical versions of the following examples:

- Jaqueline believed that Brenda said that Nancy saw him drive fast.
- Jaqueline believed that Brenda said that Nancy saw he drove fast.

---

<sup>**Notes:**</sup>

<sup>1. The one exception being when the verb is the verb *would*: *I would that you were here.*</sup>

<sup>2. If the person only saw part of the event in progress we can use a non-finite participle instead of the plain form: *Nancy saw Bill **stealing** the money*.</sup>

Comment: +1, good answer. I don’t think the focus on semantics (witness vs understand) is really necessary, though. It’s perfectly possible and normal for _see_ to mean ‘witness’ with content clauses as well (“I looked in and saw that he was sleeping”). In fact, if we add an extra _that_ to the sentence from the question here to make it unambiguously a content clause, I find it extremely difficult to force _saw_ into meaning ‘understood’ here. Jack believed that Bob said that Nancy _observed_ that Bill drove fast yesterday.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I get your point, but I think there's something more.  Consider "*Actually, I saw him steal the money, but I didn't realise that's what he was doing*", which seems unremarkable to me, with "*Actually, I saw that he was stealing the money, but I didn't realise that's what he was doing*". That last example is contradictory for me. I reckon seeing someone do something may involve you apprehending what was happening, but must involve you witenessing it. Conversely seeing that someone did something may involve you witessing it, but must involve you understanding that it happened.

Comment: I agree, though I think that’s more to do with the semantics of the object than the verb. A non-finite clause (whether participial or infinitival) seems semantically to represent a more neutral observation of an action seen ‘externally’, whereas a content clause describes the action more ‘from within’… if that makes sense. The content clause implicitly includes an element that its contents are known in detail. In this example, it describes not just the observable acts involved in stealing the money, but the actual fact that money-stealing is what it is.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yes, I think that's right.

Answer (score 2):

Since the conversation is indirect , the reporting of a past event should be in a continuous tense.

Jack believed that Bob said that Nancy saw Bill **driving** fast yesterday.

Comment: I think ***driving*** and ***drive*** both work.

Comment: Both instances of "that" can, and should for simplicity's sake be omitted. It makes the sentence easier to read and say as "Jack believed Bob said Nancy saw Bill drive fast, yesterday".